# Azure SQL External table of Azure Table storage data

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage

Is it possible to create an external table in Azure SQL of the data residing in Azure Table storage?

Answer (score 2):

Answer is **no**.

I am currently facing similiar issue and this is my research so far:

Azure SQL Database doesn't allow Azure Table Storage as a external data source.

Sources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-file-format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Reason:

- The possible data source scenarios are to copy from Hadoop (DataLake/Hive,..), Blob (Text files,csv) or RDBMS (another sql server). The Azure Table Storage is not listed.
- The possible external data formats are only variations of text files/hadoop: Delimited Text, Hive RCFile, Hive ORC,Parquet.
- Note -  even copying from blob in JSON format requires implementing custom data format.

Workaround:

- Create a copy pipeline with Azure Data Factory.
- Create a copy
  function/script with Azure Functions using C# and manually transfer
  the data

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a couple options. Please see the following:

[CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**APPLIES TO:** SQL Server (starting with 2016) Azure SQL Database Azure SQL Data Warehouse Parallel Data Warehouse

> Creates an external table for PolyBase, or Elastic Database queries. Depending on the scenario, the syntax differs significantly. An external table created for PolyBase cannot be used for Elastic Database queries. Similarly, an external table created for Elastic Database queries cannot be used for PolyBase, etc.

[CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**APPLIES TO:** SQL Server (starting with 2016) Azure SQL Database Azure SQL Data Warehouse Parallel Data Warehouse

> Creates an external data source for PolyBase, or Elastic Database queries. Depending on the scenario, the syntax differs significantly. An external data source created for PolyBase cannot be used for Elastic Database queries. Similarly, an external data source created for Elastic Database queries cannot be used for PolyBase, etc.

What is your use case?

Comment: 80% of my organization's data is residing in Azure SQL and rest is in Azure table storage. I just want to analyze the both together. The best way I think is to create a external table in Azure SQL to the data pointing to Azure table storage. What do you reckon?

Comment: And I am choosing Azure table because I have been getting 1GB of Json data daily since 2015 which Azure SQL wont be able to handle and cosmos db is expensive. I dont think I can use appendblob because it has 195GB upper limit.